# rmarkdown error: "myfile.tex"' had status 1

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to compile an RMarkdown document from an R script. This is the code I am running:

```
setwd("C:/Users/me/me_VN02_5676/myfolder")

rmarkdown::render("myrmd.Rmd",
                    output_file = "mypdf.pdf")
```

This results in the error:

```
Error: Failed to compile mypdf.tex.
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "mypdf.tex"' had status 1
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

### Additional Notes

- The PDF file is created when I use the `Knit` button in RStudio
- This code does produce the .Tex file and when I run that it produces the pdf but render() does not produce the pdf
- When I run the .R file via the command line it works! The PDF is created but why doesn't it work in R studio?

Comment: In your path `"C://Users//me/me_VN02_5676//myfolder"`, you have double slashes everywhere except between `me` and `me_VN02_5676`. Is it wanted?

Comment: I'm stuck on same error now.. Tried reinsall rstudio/miktex and etc. Still rmarkdown::render doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to provide a Minimal Working Example so that we can attempt to replicate the problem. However, there may be two potential causes:

### File Paths Look Incorrect

In R, they should be specified with a single forward slash: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.path.html

```
 setwd("C:/Users/me/me_VN02_5676/myfolder")

  rmarkdown::render("myrmd.Rmd",
                    output_file = paste0("mypdf.pdf")
                    )
```

### PDF Output File May be Open

Another potential cause of this is that the PDF file is open, and therefore pandoc cannot save the output PDF. Try closing the PDF and render the document again.

Link to previous issue in Knitr which relates to this: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1209

Comment: It is not the path as the file runs and it does produce the .Tex file.

Comment: Is the PDF file open then?

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If so, have you tried just running the default template by using the "Knit" button within RStudio? This will be a good way to confirm whether it is a formatting issue in your document or a problem with your system configuration

Comment: see updates. It works when I run using the knit button

Comment: If this is the case, it is important that you provide a minimal working example of the file, as it is likely to be something wrong with your file.  Trying replaceing "myrmd.Rmd" with the default Rmarkdown template and see if this still runs into an error.

Comment: have you tried: `rmarkdown::render("myrmd.Rmd", output_file = "mypdf.pdf", output_format = "pdf_document")`

Comment: Can you provide the full error messag which is displayed after `output file myrmd.knit.md`? It would help solve the problem

Comment: I am still just guessing though. Without seeing a minimal working example of your file there are different things which could be happening